# Reading stream of bytes from serial port in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, byte, ascii

I am new to c#. I have a serial (COM port) device which is streaming an array of bytes continuously. The array contains values of different sensors which are read by micro-controller. Basically the value of each sensor is shown by 8 bytes such that each byte represents an ascii character.There is no delimiter between these bytes. After 32 bytes, we have two bytes of a carriage (D) and a new line (A).

I use serialPort1.ReadExisting() to read data from serial port and then display readings in a textbox. However, I need the numeric values of these sensors for plotting and calculations. How can I convert these values to float numbers? Or how should I change the way I am reading serial port.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: if you read "00011236" then you can use `Int32.Parse()` to convert to integer, otherwise it depends of the encoding of the value

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let's assume the decimal value of my sensor is 12.96; then I get something like this in the middle of my stream: 32324950465754

Comment: you can try to play with bits v[0]+v[1]*256... if the evalue is integer, but if it is floating point then check what is implementation on your device manual

Answer (score 0):

To convert bytes to floating point numbers you could use the BitConverter object. Then call the ToSingle method. 
 see [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.
 It sounds like you need to read the datasheet of the device sending in the bytes to know big endian or little endian.